# Occurrences in char Array

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have this problem, 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
        at Exercise_12_2.main(Exercise_12_2.java:28)
When i am trying to just simply count the occurrences of the letters in a char array. I just cant seem to wrap my head around how to work it out. I have been at it for several hours. Please help get me on the right track.

```
input: a a a b b c !
Expected output:

Counts:
a    3
b    2
c    1
```

This is my code so far. Please help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise_12_2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Setup scanner

        char[] charArray = new char[100];
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        char tempinput = '?';

        System.out.print("Enter letters (or ! to quit): ");

        while (tempinput != '!')
        {
            tempinput = (input.next()).charAt(0);
            charArray[tempinput]++;

            for (int c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= charArray.length; k++)
                {
                    if (c == charArray[k])
                    {
                        counts[c] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void displayCounts(int[] counts)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
        {
            if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a'));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(counts[i] + " " + (char)(i + 'a') + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100` means you are asking for the 101st element of an array with only 100 elements. Remember, java arrays are indexed starting with 0.

From that you might be able to tell why this line is broken:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= charArray.length; k++)
```

`charArray.length` is `100`, so you run up until `k` is `101`, meaning that you try `charArray[100]` which is asking for the 101st element of `charArray`, *but* `charArray` only has 100 elements.

If you switch `k <= charArray.length` to `k < charArray.length` you should get farther.

On an unrelated note, `counts[c] += 1;` won't work. The `int` val of a `char` is its ascii value. The letter `a` for example is `97`, so you'll go way off the end of your `counts` array. This also doesn't account for upper/lower case (which have different numeric values).

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU. This helped a ton. I feel blind. Makes much more sense now. I really appreciate it

Comment: @IsaacPeterson, please read the edit starting with "On an unrelated note". Also  I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem becomes ***much*** easier if you use an appropriate data structure. For example, I would use a `Map<Character, Integer>` to keep the count and then iterate that to display. Like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Setup scanner
System.out.print("Enter letters (or ! to quit): ");
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
char ch;
while ((ch = Character.toLowerCase(input.next().charAt(0))) != '!') {
    map.put(ch, map.getOrDefault(ch, 0) + 1);
}
System.out.println("Counts:");
for (int c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    if (map.containsKey((char) c)) {
        System.out.printf("%c\t%d%n", c, map.get((char) c));
    }
}
```

Which I tested with your example input, and I get as requested:

```
Enter letters (or ! to quit): a a a b b c !
Counts:
a   3
b   2
c   1
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, It works. I just haven't learned about Map and HashMap stuff yet. I will refer back to this when I do.

Answer (score 0):

I think after creating the character array of `[a, a, b c, d, !, ..]`, following code will be enough to calculate count for each alphabet `[a-z]`.

```
for (int k = 0; k < charArray.length; k++)
    {
        char c = charArray[k];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
        {
            counts[c - 'a'] += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will definitely give this a try. Thanks!